# Is there a way to fill navigation properties without saving an entity to the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say I have an entity `PersonEntity` with a property `EyeColorId` and navigation property of type `EyeColorEntity`. Is there a way to prefetch the `EyeColorEntity` without saving the entity and without just querying for the `EyeColor`.

Ex.

```
public class PersonEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EyeColorId { get; set; }
    public EyeColorEntity EyeColor { get; set; }
}

public void FillFromDbExample(DbContext context)
{
    var personEntity = new PersonEntity()
    {
        EyeColorId = 5
    };
    context.SetNavigationProperties(personEntity);
}
```

Theoretically this would fill the navigation property on the entity. The result would look something like this.

```
personEntity =
{
    EyeColorId = 5,
    EyeColor =
    {
        Id = 5,
        Color = "Blue"
    }
}
```

The trick here is that I don't want to have to individually query for each property and I don't want to have to save the entity to the database to pull these properties back. Does something like the described functionality exist in EnityFramework 6.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-load all properties in the context to make *relationship fixup* work. For example:

```
context.EyeColors.Load();
var personEntity = new PersonEntity()
{
    EyeColorId = 5
};
context.Persons.Attach(personEntity);
```

In the last statement EF automatically populated `personEntity.EyeColor`.

Alternatively, you can rely on lazy loading by initializing the entity as a lazy-loading proxy. The property must be `virtual` to enable proxy creation:

```
public virtual EyeColorEntity EyeColor { get; set; }
```

Then:

```
var personEntity = context.Persons.Create(); // Creates a proxy
personEntity.EyeColorId = 5;
context.Persons.Attach(personEntity);
```

Now EF will query the matching `EyeColor` from the database when `personEntity.EyeColor` is accessed (= lazy loading).

> I don't want to have to individually query for each property

Lazy loading does query properties individually, but it's not you who has to do it.

Note that in both cases `personEntity` must be attached to the context.